# Where I can find InfiniteScrollCollection in Maui?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I have just faced problem with upgrading Xamarin project to Maui. I can't use InfiniteScrollCollection in Maui project. Do someone knows how I can use it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR2Pi.png)
Here is photo how my code looks like

I know that in Xamarin InfiniteScrollCollection is in Xamarin.Forms.Extended library. I tried to find alternative library in Maui, but I got nothing :(

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It's preferred to use stackoverflow's markdown features in order to include your code directly in the question instead of linking to a picture of the code. Here are more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `InfiniteScrollCollection` is **not** an official part of Xamarin.Forms. It's provided by Matt Leibowitz: https://github.com/mattleibow/InfiniteScrolling. You could open an issue or a discussion in the repo and ask for MAUI support.

Comment: Or follow the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0#load-data-incrementally